# How to add my application parameters to localhost_access_log.<date>.text file

Tags: tomcat, log4j, tomcat7, tomcat6

My localhost_access_log..text file contains log data like this in my TOMCAT/logs
. 
.

```
10.20.30.51 - - [22/Nov/2013:01:37:19 -0600] GET /myapp/static/css/third-party-css/images/ui-icons_2d6482_256x240.png HTTP/1.1 200 5355 https://10.20.30.60:8443/myapp/static/css/third-party-css/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
10.20.30.52 - - [22/Nov/2013:01:37:20 -0600] POST /myapp/filter/getFilterPanelState HTTP/1.1 200 28 https://10.20.30.52:8443/myapp/pss/list Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
10.20.30.53 - - [22/Nov/2013:01:37:22 -0600] GET /myapp/pss/discoveryVSOMData?_search=false&nd=1385105800099&rows=20&page=1&sidx=id&sord=desc HTTP/1.1 200 21 https://10.20.30.60:8443/myapp/pss/ Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
10.20.30.51 - - [22/Nov/2013:01:38:20 -0600] GET /myapp/ HTTP/1.1 302 - - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
```

.
.

I want to add userid, companyid...some other my application related fields to this log. for every new log line.

```
10.20.30.51 - - [22/Nov/2013:01:37:19 -0600] GET user1 company1 /myapp/static/css/third-party-css/images/ui-icons_2d6482_256x240.png HTTP/1.1 200 5355 https://10.20.30.60:8443/myapp/static/css/third-party-css/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
10.20.30.52 - - [22/Nov/2013:01:37:20 -0600] POST user2 company2 /myapp/filter/getFilterPanelState HTTP/1.1 200 28 https://10.20.30.52:8443/myapp/pss/list Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
10.20.30.53 - - [22/Nov/2013:01:37:22 -0600] GET user3 company3 /myapp/pss/discoveryVSOMData?_search=false&nd=1385105800099&rows=20&page=1&sidx=id&sord=desc HTTP/1.1 200 21 https://10.20.30.60:8443/myapp/pss/ Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
10.20.30.51 - - [22/Nov/2013:01:38:20 -0600] GET user1 company1 /myapp/ HTTP/1.1 302 - - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

I did

1. set the companyId in my request by setAttribute() method
2. added %{companyId}r to

   patternpattern="%h %l %u %t %{companyId}r %r %s %b %{Referer}i %{User-Agent}i"/>

in tomcat/conf/server.xml

Now it working  :) :)

> **Thanks to Apache Documentation Team**

:  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve